# Export PostgreSQL SQL dump using JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Following is a code snippet showing how my Java Application is exporting SQL (logical) dumps from a PostgreSQL database.

```java
String cmd = "pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://postgres:****************:5432/" + database
                + " --no-owner --no-acl" + " --clean --if-exists -f sql/db-" + database + timestamp + ".sql";

Process proc;
try {
    proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line = null;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);

    int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Process pg_dump exitValue: " + exitVal);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

I would like to rather export SQL data using the PostgreSQL JDBC API, but I can't find any matching method in the javadoc of the library.

Is there any way to export PostgreSQL dumps without using Java Processes?

Comment: No, there is no API to extract the SQL for the tables. If you **only** want the data, you could do that with the [CopyManager API](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for the comment - I already feared that answer. I already make use of `CopyManager` and hoped that there was something similar for SQL extracting.